# how to automate connecting to SSH using python in ubuntu?

Tags: python, django, shell, ssh

What I normally do is that I open a terminal in ubuntu and type this:

```
ssh -p 2200 mydomain@ssd4.rackset.com
```

then I enter the password

I then activate my virtual environment:

```
source /home/myproject/virtualenv/myproject/3.5/bin/activate
```

then I change the working directory:

```
cd myproject
```

I then go to django shell and do some stuff in a script I have written:

```
python manage.py shell
exec(open('populate_database/populate_database_programs.py').read())
```

I then exit from  django shell

```
exit()
```

and exit from ssh

```
exit
```

What I want to do is automate all of these.

How can I do all these using Python?
I see that there some libraries to connect to ssh but I did not see entering password in non of them

I need to do all these in python numerous time. The reason is that I have a script to populate my database. To insert each record, I open a file and read from the file. There are around 70,000 files. So it takes me around 3 hours and the problem happens in here. My Host Provider disconnects me every 15 minutes. SO I decided to decide the process to a few batches. and Automate all

Comment: Try not to use a password when connecting with ssh, but a key pair. If you configure your ubuntu server to accept login with your public key then you won't need a password. You might even want to block access with password alltogether, much safer anyway.

Comment: Well. That is something I just heard from you and requires me to do some other research. My question has some other parts. How can I automate the rest with python.

Comment: Is the stuff you're doing in the django shell also something standard? I mean you want to perform the same action every time?

Comment: I added some explanation

Comment: Why do you do this manually and don't write a data migration so you can run it with one command `python manage.py migrate &`? You data migration can loop through the files, read them, write the data to the db, etc... Even if you get disconnected while it's running it would still be running.

Comment: What I explained is after migration. It is complicated. I have a complicated database schema and I have to do what I explained. I will add some additional data to my question to make it more clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199084/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-amin-ba).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just creating data in your database (i.e this will happen only one time), I would advise you to create a data migration using Django's [`RunPython`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/migration-operations/#runpython). You can loop through all your files and insert the data in your db in one go. Just plug-in your existing python script. Even if the operation takes a long time and you get disconnected, it won't kill the process. Just run it via `manage.py migrate &` to make it background process.

If you're dealing with something you want to do regularly, like deploying your website, or some regular clean-up task you need to do, then [Fabric](https://www.fabfile.org) is a good way to script your automated tasks over SSH with python. It's typically used to automate deployments on smaller scale systems.

For more complex things, there are frameworks like Ansible, Chef, Puppet. These will also help you manage configurations.

Answer (score 0):

my answer is not about automating
but i can't fit them in comments

if you are being bothered on `My Host Provider disconnects me every 15 minutes.`
try [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) over ssh
this is the perfect tool fighting against disconnections

add `-t` to your ssh command

```
ssh -t -p 2200 mydomain@ssd4.rackset.com
```

start screen sessions by

```
screen
## you may feel nothing happened 
##to confirm you have active sessions 
screen -ls 
There is a screen on:
        23216.pts-2.ssd4.rackset.com      (Attached)
## here 23216 is a session id 
## go on with your work here
```

when you were disconnected by provider
you can resume your session by screen session id

```
ssh -t -p 2200 mydomain@ssd4.rackset.com
screen -r 23216
```

and you are back to where you were disconnected
all processes you started in screen session keeps alive  with the session

Comment: I used screen to fight this. I had not mentioned that there are two types of disconnection. One of them is a disconnection from the SSH that I overcame using screen. The other one is a disconnection from the Django shell. I see "killed" as an error.  The method of using data migration solves the problem. However, I am still curious about how to use Fabric to automate SSH connection.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to use django data migrations, the first option advised by @dirkgroten .
The point is that using this method instead of using django shell to populate database is way faster!! Using the django shell method, it took the database1 around 4 hours to be populated. Using the data migration method, it took around 20 minutes!